# Error when creating Facebook Messenger Channel for Azure Bot

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger, azure-bot-service

I'm getting this error when configuring Facebook Messenger Channel for a Azure bot.
May be because of recent Facebook Platform changes.
Is there any solution for this error?

[image: Failed to register with Facebook]

Comment: Facebook has currently suspended adding new bots due to the cambridge analytica scandal. Might be related to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to what Akshay has pointed out, that Facebook is currently suspending adding new bots:

> As it relates to Messenger, we are currently pausing app review, which means there will be no new bots/experiences added to the platform while we review our policies and make necessary adjustments.

Below is a link to the announcement from Facebook:
https://messenger.fb.com/newsroom/messenger-platform-changes-in-development/